# windows npm err while installing yo angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, npm, yo

i'm trying to install yo angular fullstack, using those versions:

- node v5.7.0
- npm 3.7.3
- yo 1.6.0
- bower 1.7.7

I'm getting some `npm` err

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Sahar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.4.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.4.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sahar\Desktop\Clones\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you running the command prompt with administrative privileges?

Comment: This is a PITA on windows. I'd suggest you install a flavour of linux and call it a day.

Comment: Your `npm` install is out of date. Did you try upgrading `nodejs` and `npm` as the log suggests? Grab the [nodejs msi](https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/), it includes `npm`. Alternatively, [upgrade npm by hand](https://github.com/npm/npm#windows-install-or-upgrade) if the latest `npm` is not included in the `nodejs` installer.

Comment: I'm running cmd with admin privileges, and installing nodeJS and NPM again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a widows issue. Highly recommended to use node on Linux. Get virtual box and vagrant and spin up Linux virtual machines on a Windows host with a single 'vagrant up' command

I would highly recommend docker too. Get yourself a docker node image inside your VM and you're laughing.

This is the whole attraction of virtual machines, u can just kill them and create another in secs / mins and u avoid all these stupid time wasting setup issues

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Perhaps this would have been better as a comment on the original question.